# pixel type of imread

Tags: c++, opencv

What is the default pixel type of imread create? I test different images, all of them give me unsigned
char with different channels. Would imread create a pixel type with signed char if I do not ask it
explicitly?

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("lena.jpg", -1); //always give me unsigned char
```

I checked the document of cv::imread, but it said nothing about the default pixel of imread create.

The link of the document
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#Mat imread(const string& filename, int flags)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most `.jpg` images are 8 bit images. Therfore their default data-type is `unsigned char` or `char`.

Some images like `.png` or `.tif` also support 16 bit pixel value, so their data type is `unsigned short`. But it is not necessary as they may be 8 bit.

To load the image as-is in OpenCV, use imread like this:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread(imagePath, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
```

There are different combinations of these flags:

**Load as 8 bit (whatever the original depth is):**

`CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR`

**Load with original depth:**

`CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH`

**Load as grayscale (no matter how many channels the image has):**

`CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`

**Load as grayscale with original depth:**

`CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE| CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH`

In your case, `lena.jpg` is 8 bit image, so you are getting `unsigned char` data type.

### Update:

For newer versions of OpenCV, use the flags defined by enum in the C++ interface. Just replace `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_*` with `cv::IMREAD_*`.

e.g. `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` becomes `cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`.

Comment: I want to make sure the type would be unsigned char but not char, if openCV may give me signed char, then I need to check the type and do some transform if the type is not unsigned char

Comment: OpenCV won't give you `char`. On the hard disk, images are just stored as unsigned bytes. `imread` always reads images as unsigned types. But if you are worried, you may apply additional check for signed types.