# Android OpenCV imread flags fatal exception, imread works fine with no flags, pixel output doesn't match MATLAB

Tags: java, android, c++, matlab, opencv

I can't seem to figure out why my code won't run.  Namely, I can only seem to get some OpenCV functions to work, and only partially.

Slight background: I'm translating some MATLAB image processing code to Android, and my goal is  to use only java OpenCV options and avoid any JNI or c++ native code.

I've installed it and set the libraries in the project properties, also installed the OpenCV manager on the phone from the play store, and even put the native binaries in the libs folder of the project just in case, and I have this statement which causes it to work partially:

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i("Load openCV", "OpenCV loaded successfully");
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};
```

I'm doing some testing and using imread to look at the pixel at (2000, 1000) in both Android OpenCV as well as MATLAB, however testing several pixels, I see that RGB values are off by about 2 between MATLAB and Android.  For example, I'll get 162 on MATLAB, and 160 on Android.

The problem could be caused by different ways of translating indexes, but my guess it's computing the bitdepth for the jpg and translating the value to 0-255 value for each program differently from MATLAB to Android OpenCV.

Here's the original code that works fine (albeit possibly translating my image to 8 bit):

```
Mat A;
A = Highgui.imread(photoPath);
double[] testPoint = A.get(2000, 1000);
data1.setText(testPoint[0] + " " + testPoint[1] + " " + testPoint[2] + " ");
```

However when I put a flag on to load Mat A like so to load at the original depth, following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577164/pixel-type-of-imread) :

```
Mat A;
A = Highgui.imread(photoPath, IMREAD_ANYDEPTH);
double[] testPoint = A.get(2000, 1000);
data1.setText(testPoint[0] + " " + testPoint[1] + " " + testPoint[2] + " ");
```

There are then 2 problems, first eclipse doesn't recognize the library constant for IMREAD_ANYDEPTH which is odd as have this import statement:

```
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
```

so I instead fill it in with it's value (2) just to force it to work for testing.  Again I have the libraries installed and associated.  Second, after setting it to 2, I get an error like so (my logcat output of just the action causing the error) and the activity terminates:

```
07-13 23:34:54.044: W/Adreno-EGL(14982): <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateContext:2347>: EGL_BAD_CONFIG
07-13 23:34:54.044: E/OpenCV_for_Tegra(14982): Cannot create OpenGL context
07-13 23:34:54.565: D/AndroidRuntime(14982): Shutting down VM
07-13 23:34:54.565: W/dalvikvm(14982): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41609ba8)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982): Process: com.garynfox.pathogenanalyzer, PID: 14982
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at com.garynfox.pathogenanalyzer.OpenCVTest$2.onFileSelected(OpenCVTest.java:109)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at ar.com.daidalos.afiledialog.FileChooserDialog$1.onFileSelected(FileChooserDialog.java:104)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at ar.com.daidalos.afiledialog.FileChooserCore.notifyListeners(FileChooserCore.java:327)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at ar.com.daidalos.afiledialog.FileChooserCore.access$3(FileChooserCore.java:274)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at ar.com.daidalos.afiledialog.FileChooserCore$3.onClick(FileChooserCore.java:218)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at ar.com.daidalos.afiledialog.view.FileItem$1.onClick(FileItem.java:219)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-13 23:34:54.565: E/AndroidRuntime(14982):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 23:35:02.614: I/Adreno-EGL(15067): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
07-13 23:35:02.684: D/OpenGLRenderer(15067): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Now for some reason it works perfectly fine without the flag.  Why could this be?  I'm happy to provide more info if needed.  Again my goal is to avoid any c++/JNI native code at all costs as I don't really understand how to use that tool appropriately.  What's wrong with my flagging? Have I failed to setup/import this correctly? Thanks!  I need to ensure this code gives identical output to MATLAB for the purposes of the project.

Comment: try [Highgui.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/highgui/Highgui.html)

Comment: Hmm, I tried that and with Highgui.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH the variable is resolved but I still get the same crash, thanks for the idea though!

Comment: Found the answer to the question.  It was related to an index out of bounds problem!  I was not calling Highgui.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH but rather IMREAD_ANYDEPTH which didn't resolve, hence the test point never formed causing an array out bounds error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to the question. It was related to an index out of bounds problem! I was not calling Highgui.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH but rather IMREAD_ANYDEPTH which didn't resolve, hence the test point never formed causing an array out bounds error